# mysqldump with --skip-grant-tables

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

It appears the files in my `/var/lib/mysql/mysql` are borked, and I can only start `mysqld` with `--skip-grant-tables`.

Now I want to export all tables with `mysqldump --all-databases`, wipe and reinstall mysql, and re-import the tables.

Unfortunately, `mysqldump` seems to ignore the `--skip-grant-tables` option that I used to start `mysqld`. It always assumes a username even if I don't specify one (root or the current linux user), asks for a password, and then fails (because it cannot verify the pw due to the borked files).

So, how can I export tables and circumvent the credentials?

Comment: hm, it seems that suddenly it works. at least something is going on.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to remove the `-u` and `-p` parameters on the first try?

Comment: No, I think I somehow ended the --skip-grant-tables mode with something else I did in the meantime.